# Counter example for Baire's Theorem

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, rational-numbers

Theorem: Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space, and let $D_n, n\in \mathbb N$ be open, dense subsets of $X$. Then also $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} D_n$ is dense in $X$.

This statement is false if $X$ is not complete. Take $X=\mathbb Q=\{q_1,q_2,\dots\}$ and $D_n=X\setminus \{q_n\}$.

$\bullet $ $\mathbb Q$ is not complete

$\bullet$ $D_n$ is open since $X\setminus D_n=\{q_n\}$ and singeltons are closed sets.

$\bullet$ $D_n$ is dense in X. This is what I do not understand. The closure of $D_n$ is equal $\mathbb R$, but not $\mathbb Q$. But $\mathbb R$ is no subset of $X$. So is actually here the closure of $D_n=\mathbb Q$? And if, why?

$\bullet$ $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty D_n=\emptyset$ which is not dense in $\mathbb Q$.

Could someone elaborate on the third bullet?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ contains $X$. Density w.r.t. $\mathbb{R}$ means for any point $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ we can find a converging sequence of points in $D_n$ which have limit $x$. In particular, we can choose any point of $X$.

Comment: Whenever you talk about "closure" of a subset, it is with respect to some ambient metric space. While the closure of $D_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, the closure of $D_n$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$, since every element of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a limit of points in $D_n$.

Comment: @TonyS.F. your comment seems irrelevant

Comment: @mathworker21 it's not irrelevant; i edited it anyway to be more precise but the point is that if you are dense w.r.t. some set you are also dense w.r.t. any subset of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metric space $X$ under consideration here is the set of the rational numbers with the metric inherited from the real numbers. That is, given two rational numbers $p,q\in X$, the distance between them is $|p-q|$. Now if you take any rational number, $p$, then $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{p\}$ is dense in $X$, because given any rational number $r$, there exists a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{p\}$ converging to $r$. This is of course obvious if $r\neq p$, and if $r=p$, then the sequence $\{p-\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{p\}$ and converges to $r$, so that $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{p\}$ is dense.

Answer (score 1):

In that example, $X$ is $\mathbb Q$. So, it makes no sense to assert that $\overline{D_n}=\mathbb R$. Your universe here is $\mathbb Q$ and therefore $\overline{D_n}$ must be a subset of $\mathbb Q$. And, in fact, it is *equal* to $\mathbb Q$.